# How outdated is robert freitas jr Xenology

Tags: science-fiction

I'm asking this question because I don't know whether the information in Robert Freitas jr xenology is outdated or possible.

Comment: Hello user26555 and welcome to Worldbuilding :) Can you please elaborate what do you mean by Xenology and who is Robert Freitas jr and what are his particular ideas about xenology which you are questioning here? Please notice that this site is about world building, which means you post questions about the details of making a fictional world for your video game, documentary, or novel etc :) For more information, check the question and answer section.

Comment: @YoustayIgo i find that not to be quite true considering people keep voting to close my questions which are on topic and about information on world building v.v But even with limited information one can still give a decent answer, though not in depth.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the very little information that I gleened in a 10 second google search my guess is, no, it's not outdated. As far as credible or possible I have not read the work so I cannot say, but supposing he is credible at all what he said should be "possible" given it is supposed to be a translating science to the masses book, but many of those books do have things about them that are wrong. Remember books often aren't peer reviewed and as such you should be dubious of their claims.

If you want a more precise answer, ask a specific question about what is stated and people will attempt to tackle it.